# Will macOS Catalina's new features work with older iOS devices?

Tags: ios, itunes, data-synchronization, catalina

I have two old iOS devices:

- iPad Mini 1 (iOS 9.3.5)
- iPod Touch 5th generation (iOS 9.3.5).

Neither of these devices can be upgraded to a newer version of iOS. If I upgrade my MacBook Pro to run macOS Catalina, will I be able to use these devices? Specifically:

- Currently I use iTunes to sync media to my devices. Once iTunes is discontinued, will I be able to use Apple Music, Podcasts, etc. for that purpose?
- Currently I use iTunes File Sharing to transfer files to and from the various apps on my devices. Once iTunes is discontinued, what will take its place for me? Will I be able to use the Finder to transfer files to / from my devices?

My concern is that the upgrade to macOS Catalina will require a similar upgrade on the device, and since these devices can't be upgraded any further, I am worried that they will become essentially useless. Can anyone set my mind at ease?

Comment: This might be premature since Apple could cut or add features any point up to release. Why worry about a hypothetical limitation if you don’t have to upgrade? I could see this being better suited to “now that 10.15 is released and we know some limitation X, can I run 10.14 virtually on top of 10.15 and have X work still.?”

Comment: I have to agree with @bmike on this. While I think you're being very wise in anticipating this as a possible issue, the fact is Apple can add/remove functionality at any point during the beta period. For what it's worth, my approach would be to wait and **not** upgrade to macOS Catalina until you know what the impact will be in this regard. At least then you can make an informed decision, as well as have clarity on any workarounds you may require.

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold until release date. While it's all about "will" and "future" its speculation. If anyone wants to make this about a specific build of Catalina - then it's allowed under scope but most people won't break NDA to talk about things not publicly released by Apple. See [meta] for discussions on how to enter a specific build when asking about beta software.